# How to set Alert Dialog height and width in Android?

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-alertdialog, horizontal-scrolling

Here is my code:

```
@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = this;    

    AlertDialog alertChoice = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertChoice.setTitle("Title");
    alertChoice.setView(ViewDialogScreen("Test"));    
    alertChoice.show();    
  }
  private View ViewDialogScreen(String strText) {
    LinearLayout llay = new LinearLayout(context);
    llay.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(320, 400));
    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setText(strText);
    llay.addView(tv);
    return llay;
  }
```

[image]

I got the output like the above.

1. I need to show the `AlertDialog` in full screen / 95% of the Screen size.
2. I need to handle more fields in the `Dialog`.
3. How do I enable the `HorizontalScrollview` in the `AlertDialog`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the scrolling behaviour, add a surrounding `ScrollView` to your layout, which would make your `ViewDialogScreen` method to this:

```
private View ViewDialogScreen(String strText) {
    ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(context);
    scroll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    LinearLayout llay = new LinearLayout(context);
    llay.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setText(strText);
    scroll.addView(llay);
    llay.addView(tv);
    return scroll;
}
```

Now try adding some more fields and it should scroll.

Comment: I already try that.I can able to Scroll in the Vertical manner only but I need to scroll in the Horizontal Manner.When I add the HorizontalScroll it's not working .Then after setting the LayoutParams I got the same Screen size only.

Comment: If you want horizontal scrolling, replace `ScrollView` with `HorizontalScrollView` and it will automatically add horizontal scrolling when the maximum width is reached. However, there is currently no widget allowing you to scroll horizontally and vertically at the same time (google it). But the dialog will stretch vertically as far as possible.

Comment: Thanks . I got the Horizontal Scrolling.But I need to Show Alert in full screen.

Comment: As far as I have tried it, I found no other solution than just letting it stretch itself... sorry that I am no help at this point. If you really need the full-screen perhaps try creating a new Activity.

Comment: Thanks for your Kind help Michael Rose.

Comment: @karthick Well the only solution I came up with after some research is described [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/343168f6917cb076) which uses a `Dialog` instead of an `AlertDialog`:

`Dialog alertChoice = new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Light);
    alertChoice.setTitle("Title");
    alertChoice.setContentView(ViewDialogScreen("TestTestTest"));
    alertChoice.show();
`

Comment: Great!! Thank you Very Much Michael Rose

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this but you can set your own layout for dialog. Refer my answer [Android: Dialog dismisses without calling dismiss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579048/android-dialog-dismisses-without-calling-dismiss/4582689#4582689)

Comment: In my above code I can set my own layout but size of the Alert is very small. I need to show that in full screen / specified size of the layout

Comment: you can specify size in xml. is it?

Comment: For Screen Design I use Java only.But here also I specify the size of the LinearLayout...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize an `AlertDialog` you need to create a [Custom `Dialog`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog).