# Set height and width in an Dialog Box?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog, dialog

I am using a XML-layout which I am prompting as the dialog box.
Designing of XML-layout is well formatted with enough required height and width..
But when I open it as the dialog box its width is getting disturbed so how to set height and width of dialog box through coding.

I even had referred this previous [STACK OVERFLOW QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576991/how-to-set-alert-dialog-height-and-width-in-android)

Here is the code:

```
// Layout Inflater Code..
    editDialog = new Dialog(this);
        layoutEdit = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.createlayout, null);
    
    //layoutEdit.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    editDialog.setContentView(layoutEdit);

// Called the Dialogbox to inflate

updateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                editDialog.show();  
                }
            });
```

---

// XML File Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bd"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:freezesText="false"
        android:text="Enter Name"
        
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/whtie"
        android:typeface="monospace" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    </EditText>


</LinearLayout>    
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I think [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/) is useful...

Comment: please post opening dialog box code

Comment: Please post your `xml` and `dialog box` code

Comment: please let us know how you are setting the width and height. M sure you are doing something wrong, as this is pretty easily achievable thing. Post the code and let us know what you havent done nicely.

Comment: @Shafi I have posted the dialogbox code

Comment: @Jumpo : I have posted xml and dialog box code kindly please refer it and suggest me changes to solve the problem.
Thank you.

Comment: @Rshabh: One thing i see immediately is that the property android:ems="10" is unnecessary, and might be affecting the dialog dimensions too. Please remove it. It should work then.

Comment: For an in-depth discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478520/how-to-set-dialogfragments-width-and-height/41495370#41495370

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better use an activity that looks like a dialog (I feel it will be better in your case). Here is an example code:

```
    public class DialogActivity extends Activity {
/**
 * Initialization of the Activity after it is first created.  Must at least
 * call {@link android.app.Activity#setContentView setContentView()} to
 * describe what is to be displayed in the screen.
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Be sure to call the super class.
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
    
    // See assets/res/any/layout/dialog_activity.xml for this
    // view layout definition, which is being set here as
    // the content of our screen.
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_activity);
    
    getWindow().setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, 
            android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
}
}
```

This code is from api demos

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

1.**Dialog snippet:**

```
private void CustomDialog(String msg) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(YourActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams dialogParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 300);//set height(300) and width(match_parent) here, ie (width,height)

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View dislogView = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.my_custom_popup, null);

    dialog.setContentView(dislogView, dialogParams);
    TextView popupMsg = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.popupMsg);
    Button popupOk = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.popupOk);
    popupMsg.setText(msg);
    popupOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

2.Then call CustomDialog(Str) where you want to prompt in your activity.

```
CustomDialog("This is customized popup dialog!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(height, width);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view, NULL);
layout.setMinimumWidth(200);
layout.setMinimumHeight(200);
dialog.setContentView(layout);
```

Comment: Is this supposed to answer the OP's question? If you are answering a question with a code block you need to provide an explanation as well so that everyone will know what exactly your code is doing.