# How to set DialogFragment's width and height?

Tags: android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

Let's say I specify the layout of my `DialogFragment` in an xml layout file named `my_dialog_fragment.xml` and I specify the `layout_width` and `layout_height` values of its root view to a fixed value (e.g. `100dp`). I then inflate this layout in my `DialogFragment`'s `onCreateView(...)` method as follows:

```java
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog_fragment, container, false);
```

When my `DialogFragment` appears, it does not respect the `layout_width` and `layout_height` values specified in its xml layout file and instead shrinks or expands depending on its content. Does anybody know whether or how I can get my `DialogFragment` to respect the `layout_width` and `layout_height` values specified in its xml layout file? At the moment I'm having to specify the width and height of the `Dialog` again in my `DialogFragment`'s `onResume()` method as follows:

```java
getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
```

The problem with this is that I have to remember to make any future changes to the width and height in two places.

Comment: Consider accepting jpmcosta's answer. It isn't a hack and it actually fixes the issue.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

If you convert directly from resources values:

```java
int width = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.popup_width);
int height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.popup_height);        
getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
```

Then specify `match_parent` in your layout for the dialog:

```xml
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Now you only have to worry about one place (i.e. your `DialogFragment.onResume` method).  It's not perfect but at least it works for having a `RelativeLayout` as the root of your dialog's layout file.

Comment: This answer doesn't work in my case (for DialogFragment). I had to use FragmentLayout params for change size of showing window.

Comment: I have had to wrap my layout into `RelativeLayout` and it helped me. Many thanks for the solution - it saved me a lot of time.

Comment: This works great for me (Android 4.0+), once I realised this must be in **`onResume()`**, not `onCreateView()`. (My root layout is RelativeLayout wrapped in a ScrollView.)

Comment: Useful in some cases: use the whole screen width: `int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels`

Comment: you can also call this from inside `DialogFragment.onCreateDialog()`

Comment: +1 for Jonik. -1 for Richard. I always use support fragments and have never been able to get this to work in `onCreateDialog()`. Needs to be in `onResume()`.

Comment: This does work, but there are padding & margin in the customView's parent views. If I put customView's expected width and height in `getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(width, height)`, the customView will result in a smaller size. To fix this, I have to traverse parent views of customView and clear their padding & margin.

Comment: What if I want the height to be `WRAP_CONTENT` but width a specified dimension? How to pass `WRAP_CONTENT` to height in this way?

Comment: +1 for Jonic. Finally, after one long day of searching but not finding the solution. I am super-not-impressed by the image manipulation features of DialogFragment, in particular because images are stretched per default. Who ever wants that default? Nobody.

Comment: @Weekend i am facing the same issue as you i want to know how you solved it. if i set layout(anywidth, 568); the height is smaller than 568 and hence my view scrolls i want the exact height to be set in the function. What are the values of padding and margin for the default dialog android

Comment: getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT) will work. We can also pass -1(or MATCH_PARENT) and -2(or WRAP_CONTENT)

Answer (score 182):

I ended up overriding `Fragment.onResume()` and grabbing the attributes from the underlying dialog, then setting width/height params there. I set the outermost layout height/width to `match_parent`. Note that this code seems to respect the margins I defined in the xml layout as well.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);
}
```

Comment: @jmaculate - Quick question: when you are casting to `(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams)`, what are you casting it from? I was puzzled when choosing the correct import for `LayoutParams` appearing in the first 3 lines of the function. Ended up choosing `(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams)`. Is this supposed to be correct?

Comment: @Dev-iL getAttributes() returns a WindowManger.LayoutParams, but in my case I implicitly cast it to ViewGroup.LayoutParams because that's all I need (Effective Java, Item 52) -- I'll edit the question to reflect this

Comment: If you need to cast it again to `android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams`, it's useless to use `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` three lines above... You don't gain any flexibility here. Whatever, thank you for this good answer!

Comment: This is the best solution. You can even use a specific value of pixels along with MATCH_PARENT or WRAP_CONTENT.

Comment: Here is the shorthand for this...   `getDialog().getWindow().setLayout( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT );`

Comment: in my case there is no difference between  `params.height=ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` and `MATCH_PARENT` , can you suggest me a solution please?

Comment: It takes the entire space. How to give it a margin, so that on click outside dialog it would be closed?

Comment: @jmaculate if I want to change the height of dialogFragment dynamically, isn't onResume() too late and will cause slagish UI? I would have done it in onMeasure() if it was a fragment or an activity

Answer (score 119):

**UPDATE 2021**

For Kotlin users, I've crafted a couple of simple extension methods that will set the width of your `DialogFragment` to either a percentage of the screen width, or near full screen:

```kotlin
/**
 * Call this method (in onActivityCreated or later) to set 
 * the width of the dialog to a percentage of the current 
 * screen width.
 */
fun DialogFragment.setWidthPercent(percentage: Int) {
    val percent = percentage.toFloat() / 100
    val dm = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics
    val rect = dm.run { Rect(0, 0, widthPixels, heightPixels) }
    val percentWidth = rect.width() * percent
    dialog?.window?.setLayout(percentWidth.toInt(), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
}

/**
 * Call this method (in onActivityCreated or later) 
 * to make the dialog near-full screen.
 */
fun DialogFragment.setFullScreen() {
    dialog?.window?.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
}
```

Then in your `DialogFragment` in or after `onActivityCreated`:

```kotlin
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    setWidthPercent(85)
}
```

Consider the remainder of this answer for posterity.

### Gotcha #13: `DialogFragment` Layouts

It's sort of mind numbing really.

When creating a `DialogFragment`, you can choose to override `onCreateView` (which passes a `ViewGroup` to attach your .xml layout to) or `onCreateDialog`, which does not.

> You mustn't override both methods though, because you will very likely confuse Android as to when or if your dialog's layout was inflated! WTF?

The choice of whether to override `OnCreateView` or `OnCreateDialog` depends on how you intend to use the dialog.

- If you intend to allow the `DialogFragment` to control the rendering of its own internal `Dialog`, then you are expected to override `OnCreateView`.
- If you intend to manually control how the `DialogFragment`'s `Dialog` will be rendered, you are expected to override `OnCreateDialog`.

This is possibly the worst thing in the world.

### `onCreateDialog` Insanity

So, you're overriding `onCreateDialog` in your `DialogFragment` to create a customized instance of `AlertDialog` to display in a window.  Cool.   But remember, `onCreateDialog` receives no `ViewGroup` to attach your custom .xml layout *to*.  No problem, you simply pass `null` to the `inflate` method.

Let the madness begin.

When you override `onCreateDialog`, Android **COMPLETELY IGNORES** several attributes of the root node of the .xml Layout you inflate. This includes, but probably isn't limited to:

- `background_color`
- `layout_gravity`
- `layout_width`
- `layout_height`

> This is almost comical, as you are required to set the `layout_width` and `layout_height` of EVERY .xml Layout or Android Studio will slap you with a nice little red badge of shame.

Just the *word* `DialogFragment` makes me want to puke.  I could write a novel filled with Android gotchas and snafus, but this one is one of the most insideous.

To return to sanity, first, we declare a style to restore JUST the `background_color` and `layout_gravity` we expect:

```
<style name="MyAlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

The style above inherits from the base theme for Dialogs (in the `AppCompat` theme in this example).

Next, we *apply* the style programmatically to put back the values Android just tossed aside and to restore the standard `AlertDialog` look and feel:

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layout = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_dialog_layout, null, false);
        assert layout != null;
        //build the alert dialog child of this fragment
        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        //restore the background_color and layout_gravity that Android strips
        b.getContext().getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.MyAlertDialog, true);
        b.setView(layout);
        return b.create();
    }
}
```

The code above will make your `AlertDialog` look like an `AlertDialog` again. Maybe this is good enough.

### But wait, there's more!

If you're looking to set a **SPECIFIC** `layout_width` or `layout_height` for your `AlertDialog` when it's shown (very likely), then guess what, you ain't done yet!

The hilarity continues as you realize that if you attempt to set a specific `layout_width` or `layout_height` in your fancy new style, Android will completely ignore that, too!:

```
<style name="MyAlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <!-- NOPE!!!!! --->
    <item name="android:layout_width">200dp</item>
    <!-- NOPE!!!!! --->
    <item name="android:layout_height">200dp</item>
</style>
```

To set a SPECIFIC window width or height, you get to head on over to a whole 'nuther method and deal with `LayoutParams`:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    if(window == null) return;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = window.getAttributes();
    params.width = 400;
    params.height = 400;
    window.setAttributes(params);
}
```

> Many folks follow Android's bad example of casting `WindowManager.LayoutParams` up to the more general `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`, only to turn right around and cast `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` back down to `WindowManager.LayoutParams` a few lines later.  Effective Java be damned, that unnecessary casting offers NOTHING other than making the code even harder to decipher.

> Side note: There are some TWENTY repetitions of `LayoutParams` across the Android SDK - a perfect example of radically poor design.

#### In Summary

For `DialogFragment`s that override `onCreateDialog`:

- To restore the standard `AlertDialog` look and feel, create a style that sets `background_color` = `transparent` and `layout_gravity` = `center` and apply that style in `onCreateDialog`.
- To set a specific `layout_width` and/or `layout_height`, do it programmatically in `onResume` with `LayoutParams`
- To maintain sanity, try not to think about the Android SDK.

Comment: @rmirabelle - this answer actually help, you can actually write a medium blog, and can be helpful for many.

In my case I am using constraint layout and DialogFragment, so with was ignore in Android 9, below Android 9 it is working fine.

I have added - "android:windowMinWidthMajor , "android:windowMinWidthMinor" in style and it started working fine.

Comment: @Rahul https://medium.com/@rmirabelle/how-to-set-dialogfragment-width-and-height-733c5b174178?source=friends_link&sk=89b6925083afc3910c1b12f8e53b26d5

Comment: @rmirabelle Hi, First of all your answer really helped me to solve an old issue. But as a person that have to understand all, can you please explain me why if i write the code that changed the window size in 'onCreateView' instead of in 'onResume' it doesn't apply the desired width and height? It makes me crazy to do thing without understanding the reason why i'm doing them

Comment: @Eitanos30 My guess is that the `Window` object isn't available until some time AFTER `onCreateView` is called.  If understanding things is important to you (as it is to me), I have some bad news for you. Android is the most incomprehensible thing ever conceived by humans.

Comment: @rmirabelle, thanks :) if it is so bother you (and me too), so how can we develop for Android?

Comment: @Eitanos30, yes, dialogs in Android are craps. You can use `onActivityCreated` instead of `onResume`, if you use `onCreateView` instead of `onCreateDialog`. `onCreateView` is limited in many actions in dialogs.

Comment: onActivityCreated is deprecated, you should do dialog?.window?.setLayout(... ) in onViewCreated() instead.
I agree that the number of LayoutParams classes is confusing, but I wouldn't just dismiss this as poor design. The various LayoutParams classes support different features depending on the View class they are defined for (e.g. LinearLayout.LayoutParams has an orientation field).

Answer (score 112):

I got a fixed size DialogFragment defining the following in the XML main layout (LinearLayout in my case):

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="1000dp"
android:minHeight="450dp"
```

Comment: I found that I needed the midWidth and minHeight in Honeycomb - but not in ICS.

Comment: This appears to work at first glance but it probably should be avoided. The view will continue off screen depending on the device width so if you have buttons in the lower right corner they won't appear.

Comment: The view is NOT continuing off screen. The android system seems to make sure that the DialogFragment stays inside the view bounds (with a small margin), even if these bounds are smaller than the specified minWidth and minHeight.

Comment: And this seems to work even in 2021. Hat's off to Google

Answer (score 56):

One way to control your `DialogFragment`'s width and height is to make sure its dialog respects your view's width and height if their value is `WRAP_CONTENT`.

### Using `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog`

One simple way to achieve this is to make use of the `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog` style that's included in Android Support Library.

**`DialogFragment` with `Dialog`:**

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null);

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext(), R.style.ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dialog);
    dialog.setContentView(view);
    return dialog;
}
```

**`DialogFragment` with `AlertDialog` (caveat: `minHeight="48dp"`):**

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), R.style.ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dialog);
    builder.setView(view);
    return builder.create();
}
```

---

You can also set `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog` as the default theme when creating your dialogs, by adding it to your app's xml theme.
*Be careful, as many dialogs do need the default minimum width to look good.*

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- For Android Dialog. -->
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog</item>

    <!-- For Android AlertDialog. -->
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog</item>

    <!-- For AppCompat AlertDialog. -->
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog</item>

    <!-- Other attributes. -->
</style>
```

**`DialogFragment` with `Dialog`, making use of `android:dialogTheme`:**

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null);

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
    dialog.setContentView(view);
    return dialog;
}
```

**`DialogFragment` with `AlertDialog`, making use of `android:alertDialogTheme` or `alertDialogTheme` (caveat: `minHeight="48dp"`):**

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setView(view);
    return builder.create();
}
```

---

### Bonus

On Older Android APIs, `Dialog`s seem to have some width issues, because of their title (even if you don't set one).
If you don't want to use `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog` style and your `Dialog` doesn't need a title (or has a custom one), you might want to disable it:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null);

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(view);
    return dialog;
}
```

---

### Outdated answer, won't work in most cases

<sub>I was trying to make the dialog respect the width and height of my layout, without specifying a fixed size programmatically.</sub>

<sub>I figured that `android:windowMinWidthMinor` and `android:windowMinWidthMajor` were causing the problem. Even though they were not included in the theme of my `Activity` or `Dialog`, they were still being applied to the `Activity` theme, somehow.</sub>

<sub>I came up with three possible solutions.</sub>

<sub>**Solution 1:** create a custom dialog theme and use it when creating the dialog in the `DialogFragment`.</sub>

```
<style name="Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.NoMinWidth" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">0dip</item>
</style>
```

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_NoMinWidth);
}
```

<sub>**Solution 2:** create a custom theme to be used in a `ContextThemeWrapper` that will serve as `Context` for the dialog. Use this if you don't want to create a custom dialog theme (for instance, when you want to use the theme specified by `android:dialogTheme`).</sub>

```
<style name="Theme.Window.NoMinWidth" parent="">
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">0dip</item>
</style>
```

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new Dialog(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_Window_NoMinWidth), getTheme());
}
```

<sub>**Solution 3 (with an `AlertDialog`):** enforce `android:windowMinWidthMinor` and `android:windowMinWidthMajor` into the `ContextThemeWrapper` created by the `AlertDialog$Builder`.</sub>

```
<style name="Theme.Window.NoMinWidth" parent="">
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">0dip</item>
</style>
```

```
@Override
public final Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = new View(); // Inflate your view here.
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setView(view);
    // Make sure the dialog width works as WRAP_CONTENT.
    builder.getContext().getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.Theme_Window_NoMinWidth, true);
    return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: I really don't know why the hell this is not the accepted answer. This is literally THE only answer that works and isn't a hack (I'm talking mostly for your 1st solution).

Comment: unfortunately found this only after spending an hour figuring how to solve!

Comment: Solution 3 saves my life. Thank you so much

Comment: I was able to reproduce your problem on older Android APIs. Added some alternatives that might help you.

Comment: Solution 1 worked for me. i just used `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog` as parent and used this style in the constructor of `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`. Stumbled upon your answer after a research of 1 hour. Thanks and thumbs up.

Answer (score 52):

The only thing that worked in my case was the solution pointed here: http://adilatwork.blogspot.mx/2012/11/android-dialogfragment-dialog-sizing.html

Snippet from Adil blog post:

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
  super.onStart();

  // safety check
  if (getDialog() == null)
    return;

  int dialogWidth = ... // specify a value here
  int dialogHeight = ... // specify a value here

  getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(dialogWidth, dialogHeight);

  // ... other stuff you want to do in your onStart() method
}
```

Comment: +1 `getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(dialogWidth, dialogHeight);
` works perfectly for a DialogFragment. But I don't understand the safety check. why we have to check `null`?

Comment: @2943 - simply because there's no guarantee that the `Dialog` (a child of the `DialogFragment`) will be available at the time it's requested. It's possible that Android will return null when we call `getDialog()`.

Comment: @mirabelle  if you are withing the onStart callback of the dialog how the dialog can be null?

Answer (score 14):

When I need to make the DialogFragment a bit wider I'm setting minWidth:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="320dp"
    ... />
```

Comment: Best solution in my opinion!

Comment: what if you wanna make it narrower?

Answer (score 11):

I don't see a compelling reason to override `onResume` or `onStart` to set the width and height of the `Window` within `DialogFragment`'s `Dialog` -- these particular lifecycle methods can get called repeatedly and unnecessarily execute that resizing code more than once due to things like multi window switching, backgrounding then foregrounding the app, and so on. The consequences of that repetition are fairly trivial, but why settle for that?

Setting the width/height instead within an overridden `onActivityCreated()` method will be an improvement because this method realistically only gets called once per instance of your `DialogFragment`. For example:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    assert window != null;

    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = window.getAttributes();
    layoutParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    window.setAttributes(layoutParams);
}
```

Above I just set the width to be `match_parent` irrespective of device orientation. If you want your landscape dialog to not be so wide, you can do a check of whether `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT` beforehand.

Answer (score 7):

In my case `DialogFragment` occupied full activity size like a `Fragment`. The `DialogFragment` was based on XML-layout, not `AlertDialog`. My mistake was adding the dialog fragment to `FragmentManager` as a usual fragment:

```
fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.run {
    replace(R.id.container, MyDialogFragment.newInstance(), MyDialogFragment.TAG)
    addToBackStack(MyDialogFragment.TAG)
}?.commitAllowingStateLoss()
```

Instead I need to `show` the dialog fragment:

```
val dialogFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance()
fragmentManager?.let { dialogFragment.show(it, MyDialogFragment.TAG) }
```

After some editing (I have `ViewPager2` in the layout) the dialog fragment became too narrow:

[image]

I used the solution of [N1hk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52467320/2914140):

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    dialog?.window?.attributes?.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    dialog?.window?.attributes?.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
}
```

Now it has defined width and height, not full activity size.

I want to say about `onCreateView` and `onCreateDialog`. If you have a dialog fragment based on layout, you can use any of these 2 methods.

1. If you use `onCreateView`, then you should use `onActivityCreated` to set width.
2. If you use `onCreateDialog` instead of `onCreateView`, you can set parameters there. `onActivityCreated` won't be needed.

   override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
   super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)

   ```
    val view = activity?.layoutInflater?.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null)

    val dialogBuilder = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context!!).apply { // Or AlertDialog.Builder(context!!).apply
        setView(view)
        // setCancelable(false)
    }

    view.text_view.text = "Some text"

    val dialog = dialogBuilder.create()
    // You can access dialog.window here, if needed.

    return dialog
   ```

   }

Comment: You saved my day, setting width in onActivityCreated  worked for me.

Comment: I'm using fragments, for me I used in onViewCreated like:  
`override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        dialog?.window?.attributes?.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        dialog?.window?.attributes?.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT`  And it wouldn't work without the height too

Comment: @C.Hellmann, thank you! Agree, probably this behaviour has changed in API 30, I will update the answer.

Answer (score 6):

The dimension in outermost layout doesn't work in dialog. You can add a layout where set dimension below the outermost.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="xxdp"
    android:layout_height="xxdp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it setting the root element layout parameters.

```
int width = activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
int height = activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
content.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height));
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to set DialogFragment width/height in xml.  Just wrap your viewHierarchy in a Framelayout (any layout will work) with a transparent background.

A transparent background seems to be a special flag, because it automatically centers the frameLayout's child in the window when you do that. You will still get the full screen darkening behind your fragment, indicating your fragment is the active element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@color/background_material_light">

      .....
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a try because if it works consistently, it's a VASTLY superior approach to coding part of the layout in XML and part of it in code.  Thanks

Comment: I like the idea of this approach, but when tested, it yields a different layout than simply changing height and width programmatically. For instance, the  overall width is forcibly reduced to the max width afforded by an AlertDialog (presumably because of Android styles). When I just set w and h via code, the AlertDialog style is overruled. This may fit many needs however and is a fine idea. Long live the worst SDK in history.

Comment: Worked great for onCreateView, until I wanted to change the inner width to match_parent...

Answer (score 5):

You can use percentage for width.

```
<style name="Theme.Holo.Dialog.MinWidth">
<item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">70%</item>
```

I used Holo Theme for this example.

Answer (score 5):

I took @rmirabella 's answer and updated it to also deal with height:

```kotlin
private fun DialogFragment.setSize(widthPercentage: Int, heightPercentage: Int) {
    val newWidth = widthPercentage.toFloat() / 100
    val newHeight = heightPercentage.toFloat() / 100
    val dm = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics
    val rect = dm.run { Rect(0, 0, widthPixels, heightPixels) }
    val percentWidth = rect.width() * newWidth
    val percentHeight = rect.height() * newHeight
    dialog?.window?.setLayout(percentWidth.toInt(), percentHeight.toInt())
}
```

Then in your `DialogFragment` in or after `onStart()`:

```kotlin
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    setSize(
        widthPercentage = 100,
        heightPercentage = 80
    )
}
```

Comment: Literally this is the answer in this really long thread of replies^

Answer (score 4):

Here is kotlin version

```
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        val params:ViewGroup.LayoutParams = dialog.window.attributes
        params.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        params.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        dialog.window.attributes = params as android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can below code to set layout width and height from java.

```
final AlertDialog alertDialog  = alertDialogBuilder.create();
final WindowManager.LayoutParams WMLP = alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();

WMLP.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
WMLP.y = mActionBarHeight;
WMLP.x = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.unknown_image_width);

alertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(WMLP);
alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the Parent layout of Custom dialogue layout to **RelativeLayout**,  get common width and height automatically .

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: This worked for me.  I wanted to use a ConstraintLayout to lay out the controls in my dialog so I used a RelativeLayout for the root layout and then put a ConstraintLayout directly inside it.  This gave me a normal sized dialog. When I put the ConstraintLayout as the root without changing anything else then the dialog width imploded to not very wide!

Answer (score 3):

Easy and solid:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        // Sets the height and the width of the DialogFragment
        int width = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        int height = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(width, height);

        super.onResume();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work perfectly.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    if(window == null) return;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = window.getAttributes();
    params.width = 400;
    params.height = 400;
    window.setAttributes(params);
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much what the accepted answer from 3+ years ago says.

Answer (score 3):

None of the other answers worked for me. It was solved for me only be **creating a style** where you can choose **percentage of the screen** that you want your dialog to take:

```
<style name="RelativeDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowFixedWidthMajor">90%</item>
    <item name="windowFixedWidthMinor">90%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">90%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">90%</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
</style>
```

Than just set this style to the dialog like:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.RelativeDialog)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I create the dialog using AlertDialog.Builder so I used Rodrigo's answer inside a OnShowListener.

```
dialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {

            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
                display.getMetrics(outMetrics);
                dialog.getWindow().setLayout((int)(312 * outMetrics.density), (int)(436 * outMetrics.density));
            }

        });
```

Comment: (Mainly for future readers:) See comment by `Snicolas` in the discussion of "`DialogFragment` vs `AlertDialog`" in http://stackoverflow.com/a/7979823/3372061 .

Answer (score 2):

Working on Android 6.0, ran into the same issue. `AlertDialog` would default to predefined `width` set in the theme regardless of the actual `width` set in the custom view's root `Layout`. I was able to get it to set properly adjusting the `width` of the `loading_message` `TextView`. Without investigating further, it seems that sizing the actual elements and having the root `Layout` wrap around them makes it work as expected. Below is an XML layout of a loading dialog which sets `width` of the the dialog correctly. Using the [this library](https://github.com/rahatarmanahmed/CircularProgressView) for the animation.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/custom_color"
    android:padding="@dimen/custom_dimen">
    <com.github.rahatarmanahmed.cpv.CircularProgressView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/progress_view"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:cpv_color="@color/white"
        app:cpv_animAutostart="true"
        app:cpv_indeterminate="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loading_message"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progress_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/custom_dimen"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/custom_string"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add to your `FragmentDialog`:

```
public void onResume() {
    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    Point size = new Point();
    Display display = window.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    display.getSize(size);
    window.setLayout( (int)(size.x * 0.9), WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
    window.setGravity( Gravity.CENTER );
    super.onResume();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was caused by `align_parentBottom="true"` given to a view inside a `RelativeLayout`. Removed all the alignParentBottom's and changed all the layouts to vertical LinearLayouts and problem gone.

Answer (score 1):

One of the earlier solutions almost worked. I tried something slightly different and it ended up working for me.

(Make sure you look at his solution)
This was his solution.. [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbEH3.png)
It worked except for: builder.getContext().getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.Theme_Window_NoMinWidth, true);

I changed it to

```
 @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        // Get layout inflater
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        // Set layout by setting view that is returned from inflating the XML layout
        builder.setView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_window_layout, null));


        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        dialog.getContext().setTheme(R.style.Theme_Window_NoMinWidth);
```

The last line is whats different really.

Answer (score 1):

## This is the simplest solution

The best solution I have found is to override `onCreateDialog()` instead of `onCreateView()`.  setContentView() will set the correct window dimensions before inflating.  It removes the need to store/set a dimension, background color, style, etc in resource files and setting them manually.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.fragment_dialog);

    Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button);
    // ...
    return dialog;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    if (dialog != null)
    {
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(-1, -2);
        dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
        Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = window.getAttributes();
        params.dimAmount = 1.0f;
        window.setAttributes(params);
        window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **RelativeLayout** as a parent for **DialogFragment**

Comment: Please don't post [the same answer twice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68407183/10871073).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onResume() {

    Window window = Objects.requireNonNull(getDialog()).getWindow();
    Point size = new Point();
    assert window != null;
    Display display = window.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    display.getSize(size);
    window.setLayout( (int)(size.x * 0.9), (int) (size.y * 0.75));
    window.setGravity( Gravity.CENTER );
    super.onResume();
    

}
```

Comment: Please add a sentence or two to explain what is different about your answer here as compared to other answers to this thread. Thanks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

To get a Dialog that covers almost the entire scree: First define a ScreenParameter class

```
public class ScreenParameters
{
    public static int Width;
    public static  int Height;

    public ScreenParameters()
    {
        LayoutParams l = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        Width= l.width;
        Height = l.height;
    }
}
```

Then you have to call the ScreenParamater before your getDialog.getWindow().setLayout() method

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    ScreenParameters s = new ScreenParameters();
    getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(s.Width , s.Height);
}
```