# How to specify a minimum width for FragmentDialog?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

How to specify a minimum width for FragmentDialog?

```
class TestImage extends DialogFragment{ 
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()); 
        TableLayout table = new TableLayout(getActivity()); 
        TableRow row = new TableRow(getActivity()); 
        row.addView(new ImageButton(getActivity())); 
        row.addView(new ImageButton(getActivity())); 
        table.addView(row); 
        adb.setView(table); 
        return adb.create(); 
    } 
}
```

answer proposed in this location does not help.
[How to set DialogFragment's width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478520/how-to-set-dialogfragments-width-and-height)

Comment: f.e `android:minWidth="1000dp"`in xml

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:minWidth="300dp"` in XML.

Check http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding for where to put it.