# How to create a fragment inside a dialog?

Tags: android, fragment

I need to show fragment inside of the dialog. Is it possible to give dialog theme or add fragment layout in dialog.

Comment: what you want to show in dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google merged them for you :) , you can use [DialogFragment -->](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

Comment: can we do our own dimensions for dialogfragment

Comment: Yes you can. Have a look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478520/how-to-set-dialogfragments-width-and-height

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do this.Put android.theme.dialog in the manifest file and extend the dialog with the fragment

Comment: how can we add two extends for a java class