# How to change size of standard alert dialog and make it bigger?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have standard AlertDialog popping up with results of my game, i want to make it bigger.
This is my dialog creation and setting code:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    win_lose_view = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.win_lose_screen, null);
    adb.setView(win_lose_view);
    upper_text = (TextView) win_lose_view.findViewById(R.id.upper_text);
    upper_text.setRotation(180);
    lower_text = (TextView) win_lose_view.findViewById(R.id.lower_text);
    upper_decide = (Button) win_lose_view.findViewById(R.id.upper_decide);
    upper_decide.setRotation(180);
    lower_decide = (Button) win_lose_view.findViewById(R.id.lower_decide);
    Dialog d = adb.create();
    d.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    return d ;
}

@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog){
    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
    upper_decide = (Button) win_lose_view.findViewById(R.id.upper_decide);
    upper_decide.setRotation(180);
    lower_decide = (Button) win_lose_view.findViewById(R.id.lower_decide);     
    };
    if(first_player_points > second_player_points){
        upper_text.setText("you win! score: " + first_player_points);
        lower_text.setText("you lose! score: "+ second_player_points);
    }
}
```

here is how it looks on the device:
[image: ttt]

I want to make it wider - how do I do that?

Comment: Create a custom view with the same behavior of Dialog ? Relative Layout with view in Center and dark background maybe ?

Comment: you mean, not using any standard alert dialog? just load it on game end?

Comment: Yes exactly. For what you ask is not a good practice to Google. The dialogs have a maximum size observed. In your case it is exeptional. So I think you should create a exeptionnel behavior for that.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478520/how-to-set-dialogfragments-width-and-height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478520/how-to-set-dialogfragments-width-and-height)

Answer (score 2):

Use getWindow().setLayout(width,height) after the show dialog.

```
alertDialogBuilder
        .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, close
                // current activity
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
          })
        .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, just close
                // the dialog box and do nothing
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }).show().getWindow().setLayout(600,500);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create you costume layout and set on the onCreateDialog Method.

```
 @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = View.inflate(getActivity(),      R.layout.thalicancle_dialog, null);

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), 0);

        dialog.setContentView(view);
```

}

Custome Layout XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@mipmap/popupbg"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use layoutParams , and change the attributes.

```
    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Test Dialog")
        .setMessage("This should expand to the full width")
        .show();
        //Grab the window of the dialog, and change the width
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
         lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
        //This makes the dialog take up the full width
         lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
         lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
         window.setAttributes(lp);
```