# Unable to set the width of custom dialog in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I am trying to show an alert dialog setting custom view. Setting custom view is ok. But I am having problem with setting the width of my dialog. I cannot set the width. It is always default with.

This is how I show dialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.meme_post_actions_dialog,null);
            builder.setView(view);
            builder.create().show();
```

This is xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="This is dialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see I set the width to 100dp. So it width will be too small. But this is what I got.

[image]

How can I set the width of the custom alert dialog?

Comment: Hi,@ Wai Yan Hein try to this link hope this can help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478520/how-to-set-dialogfragments-width-and-height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be the number of ways you can control it. Let me share with you one of the approaches by setting alert window width and height.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.meme_post_actions_dialog,null);
        builder.setView(view);
builder.setView(layout);
alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();
alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400); //<--Controlling width and height.
```

In last make sure that parent of your layout should match parent.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Comment: But how to set wrap_content?

Comment: I mean alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: How can I get it?

Comment: its not a good solution. what if mobile screen is very small...we should not give fixed height and width..as @Ahmad Aghazadeh answer we should calculate the screen first. Acc to screen we can make dialog.

Comment: LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT

Comment: @DäñishShärmà As I already mentioned that there are multiple ways.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.meme_post_actions_dialog,null);
            builder.setView(view);
int width = (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels*0.50); //<-- int width=400;
int height = (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels*0.50);//<-- int height =300;
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
```