# Changing a DialogFragment Max_Height dynamically before onResume()?

Tags: android, layout, dialog, android-dialogfragment, onmeasure

I have a custom `DialogFragment` which I want to change its max_height dynamically according to its view's content size (wrap content).

I don't want the update of the `max_height` to cause a jump in the UI so I planned to do it very early in the view's life cycle: `onMeasure()`.

But how can I then notify the containing `dialog` or `dialogFragment`?

From Dialog fragment I can get its hosted view, but I cannot register it's `onMeasure()` event.

From the view I can write code in the `onMeasure()` method, but how will I get a reference to its containing dialog?

I saw this post, but chnging the hight at the `onResume()` will cause a slagish UI (jump after the UI is seen)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24213921/311130

Comment: Do you want the height to vary dinamically?

Comment: yes, i want to set the max_height according to the dialog content

Comment: Then maybe extending `DialogFragment` is a better option. By this you'd inflate your own layout that extends with content.

Comment: I do extend but I want to change the max_Height according to the measure of the dialog content. How will you do it with avoiding UI jump?

Comment: At what point do you want to change the height of your DialogFragment?

Comment: @serg3z I want to change its max_height dynamically according to its view's content size (wrap content) at the earliest point (avoid slagish UI)

Comment: @EladBenda you know content height when called onCreateView?

Comment: I did it in `onCreateDialog()` to resize width and there is no glitch. Have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

How about `((View) view.getParent()).invalidate()` in the `onMeasure()` of whichever view. I realize it's sort of wrong but should fix your issue with a one liner.

Admittedly this becomes a lot more cumbersome if the recalculated-height-`View` is deeper in the View Heirarchy.