# Android DialogFragment does not expand with Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

Beginner Android developer here. I'm currently using Navigation Component in my project, and I have a DialogFragment which has a Toolbar and menu as a destination. However, the menu title is cut off even though the dialog could be expanded a bit more.

Here's what it looks like right now:
[image]

However, as you can see there's still room for it to expand. I want it to look like this:
[image: image2]

But I'm not sure how to achieve it without setting the layout to `MATCH_PARENT` programatically.

Here's the code for my DialogFragment:

```
package tang.song.edu.yugiohcollectiontracker.ui_inventory

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import tang.song.edu.yugiohcollectiontracker.R
import tang.song.edu.yugiohcollectiontracker.databinding.FragmentTransactionDialogBinding
import tang.song.edu.yugiohcollectiontracker.viewBinding
import javax.inject.Inject

class TransactionDialogFragment : DialogFragment(), Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener {
    @Inject
    lateinit var mViewModelFactory: TransactionDialogViewModelFactory

    private lateinit var viewModel: TransactionDialogViewModel

    private val binding by viewBinding(FragmentTransactionDialogBinding::inflate)

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        initToolbar()
    }

    override fun onMenuItemClick(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    private fun initToolbar() {
        binding.newTransactionToolbar.apply {
            inflateMenu(R.menu.transaction_dialog_toolbar_menu)
            setOnMenuItemClickListener(this@TransactionDialogFragment)

            setNavigationOnClickListener {
                findNavController().navigateUp()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my layout, which is just a Constraint Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/new_transaction_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"
        app:title="@string/lbl_new_transaction" />
         
        ...

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default parameters of `setLayout(int, int)` are MATCH_PARENT

You may try to use `FILL_PARENT` instead to see if it is able to change the width

Ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window#setLayout(int,%20int)

Comment: It seems like by default, the Navigation Component uses WRAP_CONTENT for the dialog. If I programatically do ```setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)```, it will stretch the dialog in Tablet mode, which isn't what I'm looking for

Comment: @OliverSong you can check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41495370/13511570, I've used it inside onResume() of my dialog fragment