# Resize the size of Dialog Fragment in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, resize, dialogfragment

I had tried so many ways but the size of the dialog never changed and I don't know but sometimes when I clicked outside of the dialog fragment, the dialog fragment doesn't close I mean in some special places and positions it closes.

here is the class:

```
class PopupWindowFragment : DialogFragment() {
    lateinit var mPopupWindowBinding: FragmentPopupWindowBinding
    lateinit var mPopupViewModel: PopupViewModel
    var id: Long = 0L
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        mPopupWindowBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                layoutInflater,
                R.layout.fragment_popup_window,
                container,
                false
            )
        return mPopupWindowBinding.root
    }
}
```

here is the navigation:

```
<dialog
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dialog_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.holyquran.ui.popupWindow.PopupWindowFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_popup_window">
```

**EDIT**
Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.holyquran.ui.popupWindow.PopupViewModel" />

        <variable
            name="userName"
            type="com.example.holyquran.data.model.UserInfo" />

        <variable
            name="loan"
            type="com.example.holyquran.data.model.Loan" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20sp"
        tools:context=".ui.popupWindow.PopupWindowFragment">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@{userName.fullName}"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layoutDirection="ltr"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.goToIncrease()}"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/submit_increase"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_circle_24" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layoutDirection="ltr"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.goToDecrease()}"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="@string/submit_decrease"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_circle_24" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layoutDirection="ltr"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.goToLoan()}"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="@string/submit_loan"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_circle_24" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/payPaymentLL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layoutDirection="ltr"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.goToPayPayments()}"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/noLoanForUser"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/no_loan_user"
                android:textColor="@color/gray600"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/payPayment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="@string/pay_payment"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_circle_24" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1.5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/gray500" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layoutDirection="ltr"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.goToLoanList()}"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="@string/payments_list"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_format_list_bulleted_24" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layoutDirection="ltr"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.goToUserTransactionHistory()}"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="@string/transaction_history"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_format_list_bulleted_24" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1.5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/gray500" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layoutDirection="ltr"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.goToEditUserInfo()}"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="@string/edit_user_info"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_edit_24" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/deleteUser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layoutDirection="ltr"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.deleteUser()}"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="@string/delete_user"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_delete2" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12805421/14976321) and [even this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12923805/14976321) but NONE of them worked.

Appreciate any Help :)

Comment: Please post the `fragment_popup_window` layout

Comment: I have Edited my Question. Check it out please

Comment: Already the dialog layout width & height take the `match_parent`.. Do you want to size it programmatically?

Comment: I want to make the Dialog fragment smaller than what is it now because there isn't much space between the dialog fragment and the bottom of the phone. YES I want t to resize it programiticltly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resize the width & height of a `DialogFragment` by changing the size of the dialog window;

For instance to set a 300dp width & 400dp height:

```
dialog!!.window!!.setLayout(
        300.toPx(requireContext()),
        400.toPx(requireContext())
```

But do this after the dialog layout view is created like in `onViewCreated()` or `onStart()`; not in the `onCreateView()`:

```
class PopupWindowFragment : DialogFragment() {

    //..... your rest of code

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        if (dialog != null) dialog!!.window!!.setLayout(
            300.toPx(requireContext()),
            400.toPx(requireContext())
        )

    private fun Int.toPx(context: Context): Int =
        (this * context.resources.displayMetrics.density).toInt()

}
```

> I want to make the Dialog fragment smaller than what is it now because there isn't much space between the dialog fragment and the bottom of the phone.

Now you need to know the current width & height of the dialog, and this requires to listen to `viewTreeObserver` of the dialog.

Add an id to the root ViewGroup of the dialog (`LinearLayout`): say `dialog_root`

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/dialog_root"
```

Then change the height & width within the viewTreeObserver` of the root layout:

```
class PopupWindowFragment : DialogFragment() {

    //..... your rest of code


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        mPopupWindowBinding.dialogRoot.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
            ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                rootLayout.viewTreeObserver
                    .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)

                // save default base layout width & height
                val height = rootLayout.height.toDp(requireContext())
                val width = rootLayout.width.toDp(requireContext())

                // change the width & height of the dialog (reduce by 50 dp)
                if (dialog != null) dialog!!.window!!.setLayout(
                    (width - 50).toPx(requireContext()),
                    (height - 50).toPx(requireContext())
                )
            }
        })

    private fun Int.toPx(context: Context): Int =
        (this * context.resources.displayMetrics.density).toInt()

    fun Int.toDp(context: Context): Int = (this / context.resources.displayMetrics.density).toInt()

}
```

Comment: Thanks of course if it was helpful I will mark your answer as accepted Thanks

Comment: Here is the link of the project and the dialog fragment is in ui.popupWindow.popupWindowFragment. I was wondering if you could resize it yourself because I myself get errors Thanks a million.   https://github.com/AmirAndroidDeveloper/Holy-Quran

Comment: @AmirAndroidDeveloper Do you want something like [this](https://media.giphy.com/media/ZjUlsmeSs7PcMw7oPE/giphy.gif)?

Comment: your link has a problem: media.giphy.com took too long to respond. I can not open the link

Comment: @AmirAndroidDeveloper Check [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kWcFW5TaDrDOarzaB9nGYKlnLdzZ1_4q/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Yes it is what exactly I was looking for.   Please pull a request to project on GitHub and then I will accept and finally I clone my project with your edits to my laptop , or u can push the project on your github and give me the link of the project.   THANKS A MILLION 

Comment: Or if you have created a new project please push it on your git lan and give me the link. I will merge(mix) code of your project to my project

Comment: I just copied only the dialog to a separate project to test it separately, I will pull it now

Comment: @AmirAndroidDeveloper Please replace your dialog with [this](https://pastebin.com/5tysdSSa)..

Comment: Ok just let me to try it out (test your code)

Comment: Thanks man. I have another issue that is related to android design too. I will post it as a new question and I think you know the answer. I will post the question soon so please check my profile to notice if I asked the question. again THANKS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238508/discussion-between-amirandroiddeveloper-and-zain).